# Define Range from top to last used cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to define a range from the top of a column to the last populated cell in that column but for some reason when I make this declaration it gives me an object defined error and I am really confused why this is happening. Here is the line:

```
Public Sub SomeRange
    Set rng1 = Sheets("FuzzyLookup_AddIn_Undo_Sheet")._
    Range(Range("B2"), Range("B2").End(xlDown))
End Sub
```

I am rather new to vba so any help anyone here could provide would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set rng1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FuzzyLookup_AddIn_Undo_Sheet"). _ 
Range("B2", Thisworkbook.Sheets("FuzzyLookup_AddIn_Undo_Sheet"). _ 
Range("B1048576").End(xlup).Address)
```

You have to use address, and you should always identify the current workbook so it does not auto-default. You should also use xlup from the bottom, incase you have a blank.

Comment: +1 and @user3034460 it will also help to `dim rng1 As Range` if you haven't already

Comment: It is good to note in your answer that this doesn't work for versions 2003 and below, since you're using `B1048576` as a reference. Support for 1 million+ rows was only introduced in 2007 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub GetLastRow()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim Rng1 As Range

    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FuzzyLookup_AddIn_Undo_Sheet")
    With WS
        Set Rng1 = .Range("B2:B" & .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    MsgBox Rng1.Address

End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Range("B2:B" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.rows.count)` Is my favourite, but it may include blank cells if they have been formatted by the user (ex highlighted)

if you have not formatted the cells, I would use this method. Regardless, it's better to start with UsedRange than the full number of rows(even when using xlup)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to cronos' method:

```
Public Sub SomeRange
  With Sheets("FuzzyLookup_AddIn_Undo_Sheet")
    lastRow = Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = .Range("B2:B" & lastRow)
  End With
End Sub
```

I prefer to put the "lastRow" in as an explicit variable, it makes reviewing the code simple.  Also, using the added complexity of "Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row" makes you backward compatible with older versions of Excel, where the row count was limited to just over 64k rows.